# What is the distribution of $Y$ given that $Y\sim F(\nu_1, \nu_2)\times 2$?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, beta-distribution, f-distribution

**Background**

I have a variable $X\sim Beta(2,1)$ and another variable $Y=\frac{X}{1-X}$

[wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Related_distributions_and_properties):

> If $X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(n/2,m/2)$ then $ \frac{m X}{n\left(1-X\right)} \sim \operatorname{F}(n,m)$

From this, I infer that  $Y\sim F(4,2)*2$.

Knowing the parameterization of $X$, I would like to parameterize $Y$ (and not, e.g., $Y/2$).

**Question**

Is there a direct transformation?

**What I have tried**

I ask because I have tried to simulate the transformation, but optimization often fails, and the transformed variable is better fit by  a $\operatorname{logN}$ than an $\operatorname{F}$ distribution.

```
set.seed(0)
library(MASS)
X <- rbeta(10000, 2,1)
Y <- X/(1-X)
f.fit <- fitdistr(Y, 'f', start = list(df1 = 4, df2 = 2))
logN.fit <- fitdistr(Y, 'lognormal')
AIC(f.fit) < AIC(logN.fit)
```

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5444/how-do-i-transform-the-parameters-of-the-f-distribution

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "parameterize $Y$"?  You have an explicit expression for it in terms of the $F$ distribution, which uses $n$ and $m$ as parameters, so I'm mystified about what might be missing.  Moreover, $X\to X/(1-X)$ is about as "direct" a "transformation" as one can imagine, so could you elaborate on what you are looking for as a valid answer to the request for a direct transformation?

Comment: @whuber an answer such as $Y\sim\operatorname{G}(f_1(\nu_1), f_2(\nu_2))$ for some distribution $\operatorname{G}$

Comment: I'm mystified, Abe, because you already have that answer.  It follows the lead-in "I infer that..." in your question.  From what you wrote it is a simple matter to (1) compute the pdf, (2) compute the cdf, (3) compute the inverse cdf, and (4) draw random values from the distribution.  You can also exploit all the theoretical properties of the F distribution to reason about the properties of $Y$.  Is there anything left to know?

Comment: @whuber after considering your comment and the answer from jbowman,  I realize that I was limited by software rather than theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean a direct transform to the $F$ variate?  That would be $Y = X/(2*(1-X))$, given your parameterization of the beta distribution.

Notes on your trials:

1) Your code has an error - it should divide Y by 2, as in

`Y <- X/(2*(1-X))`

2) Try comparing Y/2 to its theoretical distribution instead of using AIC, for example, using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

```
ks.test(Y, pf, df1=4, df2=2)
```

On my just-completed run, I got a p-value of 0.7991.

Then test the fit to a lognormal, which, if you use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test can be done by fitting log(Y) to a Normal with identical results (due to the monotonicity of the transform and the fact that the K-S test compares observed and theoretical cumulative distributions):

```
ks.test(log(Y), pnorm, mean=mean(log(Y)), sd=sd(log(Y)))
```

On my just-completed run, I got a p-value of 3.553e-15.

Since AIC isn't calibrated, it can't be used as a goodness-of-fit statistic in the same way that true goodness-of-fit test statistics like K-S can.

**Edit in response to Abe's clarifying comment:**

Y is distributed as an inverted beta distribution, with parameters (2,1), sometimes known as the beta-prime distribution and sometimes as the inverted beta 2 distribution (in those cases, "inverted beta" refers to the dist'n of 1/X).  In math: $Y \thicksim \beta'(2,1)$. A good general reference is Johnson, Kotz, and Balakrishnan, "Continuous Univariate Distributions" Vol. 2. The R package GB2 has the d,p,q,r functions for the beta prime as a special case of the generalized beta (which is what it really has in it); the documentation will make clear what parameters need to be set to what values.

Comment: @jwbowman I'd like to find if a distribution exists, e.g. if $Y\sim \text{some distribution}$, but given the answer to the [related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/5445/2750), I suspect there is no such transformation

Comment: @jwbowman I don't think that #1 is an 'error', perhaps a miscommunication - given $Y = X/(1-X)$, my goal is not to find the parameterization of $Y/2$ but to find the parameterization of $Y$

Comment: @Abe - Ah, I get it now.  Y is distributed as an inverted beta distribution, with parameters (2,1), sometimes known as the beta-prime distribution and sometimes as the inverted beta 2 distribution (in those cases, "inverted beta" refers to the dist'n of 1/X).  A good general reference is Johnson, Kotz, and Balakrishnan, "Continuous Univariate Distributions" Vol. 2.  The R package GB2 has the d,p,q,r functions for the beta prime as a special case of the generalized beta (which is what it really has in it); the documentation will make clear what parameters need to be set to what values.